# Matplotlib rendering a flat line or correct line for the same data

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Global Variables
#==============
L, J = 100, 100
dx = L/J
c = 1 #velocity

shape = lambda x: 5*np.sin(x/np.pi)
feature = slice(40,50)
times = (0,4,8,20)

#functions
#==============
def step(func, signal:pd.DataFrame, steps:tuple|list|np.ndarray|pd.DataFrame, *args, dt=0.5, **kwargs):
    for n in np.round(np.arange(0, steps[-1]+dt, dt), 3):
        t1 = np.round(n+dt,3)
        signal[t1] = np.nan
        data = func(signal, n, t1, dt, *args, **kwargs)
    return data

def _0State(feature:slice, func): #Creates the innitial signal
    signal = np.zeros(J+1)
    signal[feature] = [func(element) for element in list(range(len(signal[feature])))]
    signal = pd.DataFrame(signal, index=np.linspace(0,L,J+1), columns=[0.0])
    signal.index.name = 'x'
    return signal

#=====================================
def FTBS_nonlin(signal:pd.DataFrame, t, t1, dt):  #u_i^{n+1} = u_{i}^{n} - u_{i}^{n} \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(u_{i}^{n} - u_{i-1}^{n})
    for i, row in signal.iloc[1:].iterrows(): 
        signal.loc[i, t1] = row[t] - row[t] * (dt/dx) * (row[t] - signal.loc[i-1,t])
    return signal

signal = _0State(feature, shape)
FTBS_nonlin_out = step(FTBS_nonlin, signal.copy(), times)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('θ')
ax1.plot(FTBS_nonlin_out[0.0])
ax1.plot(FTBS_nonlin_out[4])
plt.legend()
plt.title('plot')
plt.show()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('θ')
ax1.plot(FTBS_nonlin_out[0.0])
ax1.plot(FTBS_nonlin_out[2])
plt.legend()
plt.title('plot2')
plt.show()
```

[Plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdHGw.png)
[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBkr8.png)

Despite plotting the same data, FTBS_nonlin_out[0.0] (blue line) in plot2 shows the actual data, while in plot1, it is simply a flat line. I have tried this with multiple kernels, python3.8 and 3.10, and I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the y-axis in plot #1 goes from 0 to -2,000,000,000,000,000,000.  In plot #2, it just goes from 5 to -25.  On such a huge scale, the small bump in the blue curve isn't visible.

Comment: Oh shoot I completely missed the little 1e18 scale measure. LMAO. Thanks